# scaling and centering a path

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a Path in Android and I want to stretch it to the full size of the canvas (screen size) and center it, i want to do this in my onDraw() event. The effect I'm going for is zooming in on the drawing until it matches the screen size.

Btw, this is a View that is drawed on as the path is created from an external hardware device similar to a wacom tablet.

So, if someone draws on the tablet lets say, the letter "a" at the top, the entire screen would show the large letter "o", ( https://snag.gy/nWB730.jpg ) but, if someone also then drew another one at the bottom, it would show the o at actual size at the top with the o at actual size at the bottom. (https://snag.gy/Mo49Z7.jpg) the screenshots are from iOS. I have it working on that platform.

Here's what I have so far

```
int width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

 scaleMatrix.postScale(pathBounds.width()/width, pathBounds.height()/height);

 drawPath.transform(scaleMatrix);
canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
```

It *kind of* stretches, but it doesn't center and it doesn't scale the top and bottom like the second iOS screenshot. Help is appreciated.

Comment: edit: i forgot to include my drawPath.transform - i used that already. can u show me an example with setRectToRect

Comment: https://hastebin.com/owejodutew.cpp - not working

Comment: not working as intended. i'll reword this: i need the path to be "STRETCHED" to screen size, and if ever, the path matches the screen size, it appears at actual size, but never can the path go beyond the boundaries of the screen size..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172632/discussion-between-david-kachlon-and-pskink).